# Misfire in cyl 7 on 2007 Suburban 1500 4x4 with 5.3 L flex fuel LTZ

Tags: chevrolet, misfire, suburban

2007 Suburban 1500 4x4 with 5.3 L flex fuel LTZ 267,000+ miles. 
Having trouble with running rough and misfire. The ODB II indicates P0307.

Checked wires - replaced though nothing is wrong, no change
Checked spark output with spark detector - solid steady spark
Plug looked wet, but with oil
Checked oil, 1 qt too high so removed 1 qt - no affect solid misfire.

Listened to all 8 injectors - all sound the same
Pulled all 8 spark plugs and commenced compression check on #7 - over 300 psi
Cylinder was overloaded with fuel and spewed gas out of pressure release of the tester.

Ran the engine starter with all 8 plugs out until gas quit coming out of #7
Compression check #7 = 145 psi, #1 = 150 psi, remainder were 185 - 192 psi
Reinstalled plugs after burning oil off of #7 plug with #1 in #7 position. Restart has solid misfire on #7

Remove power plug from spark generator for #7 - no affect, tried several others and they all made obvious difference in operation, but no change for #7

Pulled rail and interchanged #6 and #7 injectors (inspection has nothing obviously wrong), put back together and started engine - solid misfire on #7 only - tested by pulling connectors on spark generator of each.

Wires are new, plugs are 8,000 miles old, #7 cylinder had AFM lifter stuck and was replaced 8,000 miles ago as stop-gap measure to keep daughter's car running.

Have 10W-30 on last change and someone added two quarts when it only needed 1/2 qt. I removed a quart so the dipstick now shows at the top of the crosshatch.

Any idea what could be wrong? I am planning to pay to have someone put a new type of testing of equipment on to see what is happening. What should they be looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried swapping the coil on 7 to a different cylinder? a shorted coil can produce a good looking spark and still cause a misfire.

Comment: Agree with @Ben ... this could easily just be the coil which is bad. Changing it out with another cylinder will tell the tale for you. Also, that's a sizable difference in cylinder compression. This could be due to the #7 being washed down with gasoline. When all is said and done, you'll want to change your oil, because the gas will have infiltrated considering the amount you were saying was in the cylinder.

Comment: Yes, in fact her friend has connections and got a good one to replace it with before I started working on it. He replaced all the wires and as I understood it, replaced each of the coils with the new one and tried it after each with no improvement.

Comment: The tester that I have for the spark checker is supposed to be able to determine whether or not the spark is too weak. At least that was the claim. It looks like a spark plug with hollowed end and a big clip in the center. It sparked just fine.

Comment: When the first problem occurred 8000 miles ago, I bought an AFM preventer that plugs into the ODB II. It took all of the Stabilitrak and other idiot failures out. Based on those problems, I think that the PCM is questionable. The overfill with oil got the PCM off its dime and started putting the engine into limp mode. I don't know for sure, but that is what it sounds like. The transmission is shifting hard again and P0641 occurred once. No one seems to know what that is about, but it is looking like PCM to me.

Comment: My daughter's friend has a buddy who has access to a good tester after hours and is willing to help him check it out. As for the gas in the oil, I'm not concerned. I'll decide what to do if we can figure out what is wrong. Probably a new engine or another engine at least - never saw someone so attached to a car as she is. They offered her $1500 for her car or a little one for $6000 (used). She just laughed at them. If she had $6000 she would fix this one even with nearly 270,000 miles on it.

Comment: a p0641 is a 5v reference circuit 1 code. you're going to need a wiring diagram and check the 5v reference circuit 1 for a short to ground or similar. have you hooked a vacuum gauge up to the engine? have you done a power balance test on the engine? id confirm your afm disabler is doing its job and the solenoid on #7 isnt stuck on due to a bad solenoid or a short.

Comment: @Paulster2: the compression was 145 cold after I got the gas out but over 300 psi (pegged) - when I released the air, it blew a stream of gas out. So I pumped on the thing till the gas quit coming. And then took three more readings - the last was 145 psi and no gas came out. None of the other cylinders showed that. Later after I got it started, the compression on that cylinder hot with all other sparkplugs in place was 150 psi, the same as #1 - all the rest are 185 - 192 psi and no gas.

Comment: as to the spark tester those are pretty good but not fool proof you'd really need a scope to current ramp the coil. though since its been replaced its a non issue.

Comment: @Ben: I think that you are correct, but this equipment can do those tests easily, can't it? I did verify that the engine does run better with the AFM disabler installed. I think the p0641 is a bogus based on a faulty PCM, but I'll let these young guys check her out. I recognize the function of that code - it means that the sensors didn't respond correctly. When I test drove it, the shifting was poor, but all that had cleared up before when the PCM was forced to stay out of limp mode.

Comment: @Ben: I am tired of retyping this so it gets thrown away by fat-fingered exercises. I'll let them check those tests they can do and see what they come up with. 
Thanks a bunch and I'll try to get back here with the results if I ever get them ! LOL

Comment: @Ben - sorry just noticed your comment about solenoid on #7. I swapped the injectors with no change - should have followed unless the wire is shorted. I'll mention that to them. Here again I expect that the tester will measure the voltage on the solenoid and the current flowing. Should detect that, right?

Comment: whatever scantool they are going to use probably wont i doubt even the tech2 would. by solenoid i mean the solenoid that controls oil flow to the valves.

Comment: Update: I decided to test running compression and found no compression on #7. So I tore it down and found that the lifter is locked up - I think I will replace the lifter once more and try to get the last miles out of this ol' workhorse. The symptoms were just enough different to make me think something else was wrong.

Comment: Update: After the repair was done in Aug 2017, the engine ran really well for a long time. In May 2018 it began to act up again. It began swallowing oil in huge gulps, like a  quart at a time (another known issue with this engine).

Comment: It developed a rather loud 'chirp' noise that was disturbing but they drove it to St Louis from Dallas towards the end of May anyway. On the way it suddenly began to use oil, but before they got there, but not until after they had used two quarts of oil. It quit doing that and ran fine while they were there. Then on the way back they had a repeat performance and used another two quarts of oil, but then it stopped doing that again - and the chirp is gone.

Comment: However, now it misfires almost solid in cyl #7 - it has over 320,000 miles now. I am reluctant to pull it apart again, but if I don't I'm sure it is doomed. Maybe it is already.

Comment: Update: On Aug 13, 2018, our daughter passed away. In attempting to close out her estate, I repaired the vehicle again and found that the lifter had stuck again. I put it back together with a new lifter and buttoned her up once more. I needed the SUV to pull a trailer to move to our new home as the memories in the old house were too much for my wife. After the move, the lifter is ticking once more. This vehicle is now a project car and will be repaired with an engine overhaul w/o AFM

Comment: Update: in late 2018 I finished the replacement of the cam and stuff - a fool's exercise - the engine needs an overhaul! Well, I put it back together and put 5w-30 oil in it but the oil pressure would not rise. So I put in a high volume oil pump (you know what that meant , pulled it apart in the front again). The pump worked pretty good, but the oil pressure is too low. I pulled out the 5W-30 and replaced it with 10W-30 - now the pressure is high enough, but throws low pressure code on occasion so fails inspection.

Comment: So I chased that down with the special scan tool and found it was getting out of the window of 'good' value range during deceleration coming off the freeway. Had a mechanic verify. They suggested that I add a quart of oil thickener ( I forget the name) It is thick and sticky and coats the bad bearings so they don't leak so bad for awhile. My granddaughter wants the car and has used it now for a couple of years. Still less than 400k miles, but running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i can tell you exactly what the problem is you have bad lifters in the cylinder that is misfiring. Flex Fuel engines in the Suburban Tahoes Yukons have dift lifters This 5.3  engine is designed to run on 4 cylinders mostly in the cruise mode.All so these lifters are notorious for collapsing or sticking you must replace them problem solved

Comment: Yes, that is what it was. The lifter shifts to shut it off, but then can't unshift or vice versa. Then the engine beats the thing to pieces as it clickety clacks away.  The advantage of the AFM is so small that it is really a dumb feature on a GREAT engine. By reverting it to the older version with the cam and rewrite of the PCM code, it works like a champ.

Comment: However, my experience has been that 'the problem is not solved' by replacing them - they just run for a short time and faila again because the real cause is not overcome - I do not know what the real cause is, but the real fix is to get rid of that kind of lifter. The engine is very efficient and gets almost as good mileage without ever going into the 4 cylinder mode. I have a suspicion that more problems are caused by the idiocy of the limp mode than anything else.